# Query on SweetAlert Simple message box

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

I'm new to jQuery and I am new to Sweet alert too, I saw the basic alerts using sweet alert and tried to do it in my code too but its not working.
can some one tell me why its not working...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="sweetalert-master/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="sweetalert-master/dist/sweetalert.css">
    </head>
    <body>      
        <script>
        $('.show-alert').on('click', function ()
        {
            sweetAlert('Replace Default Alerts');
        });
        </script>
        <a href="#" class="show-alert">Show Alert</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points of interest in your code are:

1. The path to SweetAlert include path may be wrong. You may use:

https://rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.min.js

or

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js

2. It's necessary to call the sweetAlert on document ready (refer to: [document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)) otherwise the dom elements are not yet ready to be used.

So the snippet is:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.show-alert').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    sweetAlert('Replace Default Alerts');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>


<a href="#" class="show-alert">Show Alert</a>
```